# The task was unsuccessful: The deployment was unsuccessful due to unknown reason

Tags: messagebroker, websharper

Error Description:

The BAR File contains .msgflow files and this broker does not support them. To deploy this BAR file to the target broker save the BAR file selecting the 'Compile and in-line resources option'.

Check that,
 1. The broker is running.
 2. The TCP/IP port of the queue manager is active if it is remote.

Details Error Description:

Begin running task [Deploying [RecordAndReplyExample] to execution group [default]]

The deployment was unsuccessful due to unknown reason.

The task was unsuccessful: The deployment was unsuccessful due to unknown reason.

Did anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are trying to use features in the message flow that are not supported by the broker you are attempting to deploy it to.

From that error message, and with no version info provided by the OP, I would guess that you are trying to use a BAR file that contains .msgflow files on a broker that only supports compiled flows in .cmf files. If this is the case then you will need to either use a later version of MB/IIB that supports this feature, 8 FP1 or later, or recreate your BAR file with the 'Compile and in-line resources option' option set in the toolkit on the save BAR file screen.